# Animate point's position based on array of positions with shaders in THREE.js

Tags: three.js, glsl, webgl, vertex-shader

I have animation of thousands of points in THREE.js which change their positions in time. I want to use shaders to make the animation faster. Since I am completely new to shaders I wanted to start with animating just one point. In each time step I would like to assign my point predefined position saved in array of vectors (*positions*). So if `time = 1`, the point's position would be equal to `positions [1]`

I tried to saved the *positions* as a uniform and pass it to vertex shader but it didn't work.

What I should do differently? Is this a correct approach?

Point declaration

```
//example array with only three vectors but I would like to use arrays which thousands of vectors
var positions = [
    new THREE.Vector3(1.6, 2.5, 4.0),
    new THREE.Vector3(1.8, 2.5, 3.8),
    new THREE.Vector3(1.2, 2.0, 3.0)
]

var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();    
geometry.addAttribute("position", new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute([1.6, 2.5, 4.0],3))

var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    vertexShader: document.getElementById( 'vertexShader' ).textContent,
    fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fragmentShader' ).textContent,
    uniforms: {
        time: { type: 'f', value: 0 },
        positionArray: {type: "v3v", value: positions} 
    }
})
var point = new THREE.Points(geometry, material);
scene.add(point)
```

Animation

```
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    time = time + 1
    material.uniforms.time.value = time;

    controls.update();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    stats.update();
}
```

Vertex Shader

```
uniform vec3 positionArray[3];      
uniform float time;

void main () {

    vec3 newPosition;
    newPosition= positionArray[time];
    gl_PointSize = 10.0;

    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(newPosition, 1.0);
    }
```

Comment: I found the issue in my code, in uniforms definition I should set time to int instead of float
`time: { type: 'i', value: 0 }`
Anyway this approach does not solve the issue with slow animation....

Comment: Could you create a working code snippet or jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do without shaders.

Idea: you have an array of `Float32Array()`

```
var data = [
  new Float32Array([...]),
  new Float32Array([...]),
  //and so on
];
```

, and each typed array contains the data for each point in your geometry at a given time key; then, when time is, for example, `1`, you just assign the data from element `1` of your `data` array to the `geometry.attributes.position.array`.

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 2, 25);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setClearColor(0x404040);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

scene.add(new THREE.GridHelper(100, 100, "white", "white"));

var data = []; // arry of Float32Array
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  let arr = [];
  for(let x = -50; x <= 50; x++){
    for(let y = -50; y <=50; y++){
       arr.push(x, i * 2, y);
    }
  }
  data.push(new Float32Array(arr));
}

var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
geometry.addAttribute( 'position', new THREE.BufferAttribute( new Float32Array(data[0].slice()), 3 ) );

var material = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
  size: .25,
  color: "red"
});

var plane = new THREE.Points(geometry, material);
scene.add(plane);

var clock = new THREE.Clock();
var time = 0;
var floorTime = 0;
var oldTime = -1;
var delta = 0;

render();

function render() {
  delta = clock.getDelta();
  time += delta;
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  if (time >= 10) time = 0;
  floorTime = Math.floor(time);
  if (floorTime != oldTime) { // a very rough approach of managing the time keys
    geometry.attributes.position.array.set(data[floorTime]); // set the data of points
    geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true;
    oldTime = floorTime;
  }
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

PS Maybe such an approach is not very correct. It's just an idea.

Comment: Yes, for sure, you can do it without shaders. I just wanted to try it with shaders to learn how they work.